# ios: UITableViewCell disappear when scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm working on some kind of chat iphone app, an I'm facing a problem I do not manage to fix.
I saw several answers for this, but none seems to fix this in the context I have.

I use a TableView to display the messages and when I scroll from time to time the cells disapppear. I have to go back to the parent view (the view which navigation controller is used to push my chat view) and then go back to the chat view to see the cells.

I have the following method:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {    
   // static NSString* CellIdentifier = @"MessageCellIdentifier";
   // MessageTableViewCell* cell = (MessageTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   //if (cell == nil){

   MessageTableViewCell* cell = [[[MessageTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];
    SharethingsAppDelegate *delegate = (SharethingsAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   ChatMessage* message = [[delegate.dataModel getMessagesOfChatWithID:self.chatID] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   [cell setMessage:message];

   //}
   return cell;
}
```

I tried to keep the test "cell == nil" but same thing.
I guess this is some kind of cell re-usage problem but... cannot really figure out what it is exactly.

Any idea ?

Comment: The code looks OK, so I'm not really sure what's going on. Have you checked that `message` is still coming back as non-`nil` when the messages disappear? Also, any chance your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` starts returning `0`?

Comment: @mattjgalloway in fact I can see the rows (I use custom view cell) but the content is empty. I'll add some more log and keep you posted. Thanks.

Comment: Oh well if the content is empty then presumable either `message` is `nil` or your custom cell is not responding properly to `setMessage:` and redrawing itself accordingly. Although doubt the latter as you're currently creating new cells each time.

Answer (score 2):

I come across the same issue as like you. In my case, I'm using custom cells and in my `heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method I set their heights. When you start scrolling the cells will disappears but only if row's height become **smaller** then my custom cell's height. Otherwise it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

It might be that your `UITableView` thinks that your cells are out of sight, and removes them. This happens if the frame of the tableview is not big enough, and you are actually viewing overflowed content.

Try setting the `.clipsToBounds` property on the tableview to `YES` (in code) or check the "clip subviews" checkmark on it (in IB). This way, you will see the actual boundaries of the tableview.

Comment: it shouldn't do any trick, but it may shed some light on your problem. Could you be a little more specific on how/when the cells disappear? Does it correlate with any actions? (reload, scroll, ...?)

Comment: yes, it is linked to the load of the view (the display of all the items) and also when scrolling.

Comment: please be a little more specific.

Comment: In fact, this pb seems to occur when there are quite a lot of cell in the list. When all the cells fit the screen, there is no problem. I have a list with 30+ cells and the scroll seems to be causing the pb in this case. The strange thing is that is does not occurs every time. If I close the app (removing it from background) and restart it it is fine.